# SQL Server: update column with special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, newid

I'm new to SQL Server so please excuse me for maybe stupid question.

I have a database that I need to generate random id which I achieve by using `newid()`

```
insert into Teams (team_code, team_name, team_short) 
values (newid(),test,test)
```

But the problem is that `team_code` id need to be in curly brackets and I don't know how to do it.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks
^

Comment: Is the datatype for team_code not a uniqueidentifier?

Comment: You should add a tag for the dbms you are using (SQL-Server 2008, 2012 or 2014 probably).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way because  newid() direct not set curly brackets

```
DECLARE @ID varchar(max);
    SET @ID = newid();
select @ID
insert into Teams (team_code,team_name,team_short) values ('{'+@ID+'}',test,test)
```

AND also you try as

```
insert into Teams (team_code, team_name, team_short) values ('{'+Convert( VARCHAR(max),NEWID())+'}',test,test)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the casting inline:

```
INSERT INTO Teams (team_code, team_name, team_short) 
VALUES ('{' + CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(255)) + '}',test,test)
```

Answer (score -1):

So you want to add a leading { and a trailing } to the created unique identifier string? This is SQL Server, right? Then you concatenate string with + as shown here:

```
insert into Teams (team_code, team_name, team_short) 
values ('{' + newid() + '}', test, test);
```

Comment: This will fail since NEWID() returns data type UNIQUEIDENTIFIER (error is The data types varchar and uniqueidentifier are incompatible in the add operator.)

Comment: @koppinjo: Thanks for the correction. I thought such a trivial conversion would happen automatically.